# Adding Barcodes to Invoices

Tags: xero-api

I am looking to use a Xero API to send document (invoice) details to a database a return a unique document ID. I would then like to use that Document ID to render a Barcode that can later be scanned for processing.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, is there any consultants that can develop this solution?

Preference is for a developer in Australia.

Comment: I noticed someone called Wade asked for me at work today haha, just realised there's actually no PM function on this website. You can email me at tomdanvlog at gmail dot com if you want to get in touch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Australia and use the Xero API and barcodes. What you're asking for sounds pretty basic, but also pretty specific, so hard to find someone to do it. Feel free to PM me, I'd be happy to do it for free if it's simple.